# incompatible with attribute background (attr) reference|color in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="discover"
            type="xx.ViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/disc_dis"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/bottom_sheet_peek_height"
            android:background="@{discover.isEnabled ? @drawable/corner_dark : @drawable/corner_light}"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/to"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/to"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/light_gray_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/pd"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/disys"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    tools:listitem="@layout/item_disy_item" />

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/disc"
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/progress_bar"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/progress_bar"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/text_width"
                    android:indeterminate="true"
                    android:progressBackgroundTint="@color/background_color"
                    android:progressTint="@color/progressbar_color"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.474"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.326" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/state_message"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/pd6"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/element_margin"
                    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/element_margin"
                    android:text="@string/progress_message"
                    android:textColor="@{discover.isEnabled ? @color/text_white : @color/text_black_color}"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/size"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/disc" />

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                    android:id="@+id/btn_error_action"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/pd12"
                    android:background="@color/action_btn_background"
                    android:padding="@dimen/action_btn_padding"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/state_message"
                    tools:text="@string/expo_turn_bluetooth_on_label" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</layout>


<color name="text_white">#FFFFFFFF</color>
<color name="text_black_color">#272626</color>
```

corner_dark.xml :

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="16dp"
        android:topRightRadius="16dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/darktheme"></solid>
    <size android:height="48dp"/>
    <padding android:left="4dp" android:top="10dp" android:right="4dp" android:bottom="4dp" />
</shape>
```

corner_light.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="12dp"
        android:topRightRadius="12dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/white"></solid>
    <size android:height="48dp"/>
    <padding android:left="4dp" android:top="10dp" android:right="4dp" android:bottom="4dp" />
</shape>
```

Hi, I am getting an Android Resource Link error as below, not sure what lead to the error.

```
dis.xml: AAPT: error: '@{discover.isEnabled ? @drawable/corner_dark : @drawable/corner_light}' is incompatible with attribute background (attr) reference|color.

dis.xml:70: AAPT: error: '@{discover.isEnabled ? @color/text_white : @color/text_black_color}' is incompatible with attribute textColor (attr) reference|color.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `discover.isEnabled` return value different true or false

Comment: It returns either true or false

Comment: discover.isEnabled returns either true or false, based on that the color is picked. Is there something wrong in that ?

Comment: I think discover.isEnabled wasn't true or false. try ObservableBoolean isEnabled = new ObservableBoolean(false);